# Oracle Update query fails to update using C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to update the table in oracle. But the update doesn't work and alos there is no exception thrown. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

```
conn.Open();
string txtInsert = "Update ORDER_DOSIMETER set FREQUENCY_CDE=:ParamFREQUENCY_CDE,  RING_SIZE=:ParamRING_SIZE where SSN=pkg_encrypt_decrypt.funcencrypt(:ParamSSN,'12345678') and DOSIMETER_TYPE= :ParamDOSIMETER_TYPE";

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(txtInsert, conn);

                OracleParameter ParamSSN = new OracleParameter("SSN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);

                ParamSSN.Value = SavePersonDetails.SSN;

                OracleParameter ParamDOSIMETER_TYPE = new OracleParameter("DOSIMETER_TYPE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
                ParamDOSIMETER_TYPE.Value = SavePersonDetails.Type;

                OracleParameter ParamRING_SIZE = new OracleParameter("RING_SIZE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
                ParamRING_SIZE.Value = SavePersonDetails.RingSize;

                OracleParameter ParamFREQUENCY_CDE = new OracleParameter("RING_SIZE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
                ParamFREQUENCY_CDE.Value = SavePersonDetails.Frequency;


                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamSSN);                    
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamDOSIMETER_TYPE);                 
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamRING_SIZE);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamFREQUENCY_CDE);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Does the `UPDATE` work when you run it directly, for example from SQL Developer, with some values substituted for bind variables? Do you issue a `COMMIT` after you run this `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was with the Parameters.Add() 
The parameters should be added in accordance of there occurrence in the Update statement.
Actual order should be:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamFREQUENCY_CDE);
cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamRING_SIZE);
cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamSSN);                    
cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamDOSIMETER_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to Use Commit statement after the last statement when ever you are executing the Oracle update Statement.
Auto Commit it Fired when ever you call the Update Stored Procedure from the OLEDB Using C# 
ExecuteNonQuery()